# Improve speed of evaluating a sum over four indices

Tags: numerics, special-functions, performance-tuning, summation

I am trying to implement the Fox-H function with several variables as sum of residues. I have arrived at the following function;

```
$f[ρ_] := 
  1/π 8/(3 π Gamma[13/10] Gamma[9/5]) 
    Re[
     (I ρ)^-1 NSum[
                1/(i! j! k! n!) (-1)^(-i - j - k - n) 
                  2^(57/100 - (13 i)/5 + (3 j)/10 + n)*
                  3^(11/5 - (8 j)/5 + 2 k)*
                  5^(539/100 - i/5 + (13 j)/10 - k + 3 n)*
                  11^(-5 - 2 n)*13^(23/10 + i)*
                  (-ρ)^(1069/100 + (4 i)/5 + (13 j)/10 + (3 k)/2 + 2 n)*
                  Gamma[26/25 + (4 i)/5]*
                  Gamma[39/20 + (13 j)/10]* 
                  Gamma[27/10 + (3 k)/2]*
                  Gamma[1/100 (-969 - 80 i - 130 j - 150 k - 200 n)]*
                  Gamma[5 + 2 n],
                {i, 0, ∞}, {j, 0, ∞}, {k, 0, ∞}, {n, 0, ∞}, 
                Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]]
```

I tried to perform the inner sum symbolically to reduce the order of summation, but it still takes a lot of time to evaluate even a single point.

For example, I get

```
f[3] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {39.179758, 0.369816}
> ```

When I try to evaluate `f[8]` it takes a lot more time.

Is there a way to evaluate these multiple sums faster?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Methinks it would be far more efficient to use the contour integral definition of the Fox function, completely analogous to how `MeijerG[]` is evaluated internally. You will just need to find a (possibly piecewise) complex contour that crosses through the poles of the associated gamma ratio in the right way…